# MySQL Sort Alphabetically but Ignore "The"

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL database that has a table with book data in it. One of the columns in the table is called "title". Some of the titles begin the word "the" and some do not.

Example:

- "The Book Title One"
- "Book Title Two"
- "Book Title Three"

I need to pull these out of the database in alphabetical order, but I need to ignore the "the" in the beginning of the titles that start with it.

Does SQL (specifically MySQL) provide a way to do this in the query?

Comment: Beware that sorting titles is much more complicated than ignoring "the" (also "a" and "an" as well). Where does "Les Misérables" sort? ("les" is one of French's several ways to say "the"). The Chicago Manual of Style has a *long* list of rules on how to alphabetize.

Answer (score 9):

do a case when to check if the column value starts with the and if it does, return the title without the 'The'. This will be a new column that you will be using later on for the sort order

```
select title, case when title like 'The %' then trim(substr(title from 4)) else title end as title2 from tablename order by title2;
```

Comment: So you're suggesting that I just create a whole second title column in the DB from which to pull the sort order? Basically, I would have one column the way it currently is and then a second title column with "the" removed from the beginning?

Comment: the other column will be virtual, meaning, it is not present on the table structure and will only appear on the query result

Comment: @JoeHoskinson No he's suggesting you create the column at query time with a case statement and then order by that column in your query.

Comment: Incorrect `like` argument:  what happens if the title is *These and Those*?

Comment: then you add space after the The :D i'll rectify it. :D

Answer (score 8):

You can use a `CASE` statement in the `ORDER BY` and the use `REGEXP` or `LIKE` to match strings that start with words you would like to remove.

In the example below I find all words that begin with **a**, **an**, or **the** followed by a space, and then remove everything up to the space, and trim away additional white space (you might have two or spaces following an instance of **the**).

```
SELECT *
FROM books
ORDER BY 
  CASE 
    WHEN title REGEXP '^(A|An|The)[[:space:]]' = 1 THEN 
      TRIM(SUBSTR(title , INSTR(title ,' '))) 
    ELSE title
  END ;
```

Answer (score 4):

if you are sure that you will NEVER EVER have a typo (and use lowercase instead of uppercase)

```
select *
from books b 
order by UPPER(LTRIM(Replace(b.Title, 'The', '')))
```

Otherwise your sorting will do all Upper and then all lower.

for example, this is ascending order:

```
Have a Great Day
Wild west
Zorro
aZtec fries are hotter
alfred goes shopping
bart is small
will i am not
```

adapted from AJP's answer

Answer (score 2):

I've seen some convoluted answers here which I tried but were just wrong (didn't work) or unsafe (replaced every occurrence of 'the'). The solution I believe to be easy, or maybe I'm getting it wrong or not considering edge cases (sincerely, no sarcasm intended).

```
... ORDER BY SUBSTRING(UPPER(fieldname), IF(fieldname LIKE 'The %', 5, 1))
```

As stated elsewhere, `UPPER` just prevents ASCII sorting which orders B before a (note the case difference).

There's no need for a `switch-case` statement when there is only one condition, `IF()` will do

I'm using MySQL 5.6 and it seems like the string functions are 1-indexed, in contrast to say PHP where strings are 0-indexed (this caught me out). I've tested the above on my dataset and **it works**

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from books b 
order by LTRIM(Replace(b.Title, 'The', ''))
```

PLease note this will replace The from the title.. no matter where in the title. so use substring to get first 3 characters.

Comment: will replace word 'the' with '' as it says. i should have say first 4 charcters instead 3 and use 'the ' instead 'the'. thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

### Simply:

```
SELECT Title
FROM book
ORDER BY IF(Title LIKE "The %", substr(Title, 5), Title);
```

### Explanation:

We use the `IF` function to strip the "The" (if present) from the beginning of the string before returning the string to the `ORDER BY` clause. For more complex alphabetization rules we could create a user-defined function and place that in the `ORDER BY` clause instead. Then you would have `...ORDER BY MyFunction(Title)`.